# Filtering an ArrayList<MyClass> on the basis of a MyClass.MyString and summing up a MyClass.MyCount

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I've a Bean Class `MyClass` as

```
public class MyClass {
String myString;
int myCount;

public MyClass() {
}

public MyClass(String myString, int myCount) {
    super();
    this.myString = myString;
    this.myCount = myCount;
}

public String getMyString() {
    return myString;
}

public void setMyString(String myString) {
    this.myString = myString;
}

public int getMyCount() {
    return myCount;
}

public void setMyCount(int myCount) {
    this.myCount = myCount;
}}
```

I have an ArrayList as

```
MyClass obj1 = new MyClass("1-ABC_2-PQR_1-PQR_1-DEF", 4);
    MyClass obj2 = new MyClass("1-ABC_2-PQR_3-XYZ_1-PQR_1-DEF", 12);
    MyClass obj3 = new MyClass("1-ABC_1-PQR_1-DEF", 3);
    MyClass obj4 = new MyClass("3-ABC_2-PQR_1-DEF", 3);
    ArrayList<MyClass> rawList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
    rawList.add(obj1); rawList.add(obj2); rawList.add(obj3); rawList.add(obj4);
```

For the whole ArrayList I am picking out the `MyClass.myString` iteratively and based on a selection criteria tailoring them and setting them back to their respective objects. After this, I need to create a New ArrayList in which if myString for one object matches that of the other then I need to add the `MyClass.myCount` for them both and delete of one of the objects.

For example, in the values I've taken, if after tailoring `obj1.getMyString()` matches `obj3.getMyString()` as **1-ABC_1-PQR_1-DEF** then I need to add `obj1.getMyCount()` and `obj3.getMyCount()` and save only one of them in the new ArrayList.

I am doing this in the following way, but I am hoping to get a efficient and fail proof way to do this.

```
  int j = 0;
            if (rawList.size() > 0)
                list.add(rawList.get(0));
            for (int i = 1; i < rawList.size(); i++) {
                if (rawList.get(i).getMyString()
                        .equals(list.get(j).getMyString())) {
                    list.get(j).setMyCount(
                            list.get(j).getMyCount()
                                    + rawList.get(i)
                                            .getMyCount());
                } else {
                    j++;
                    list.add(rawList.get(i));
                }
            }
```

Comment: `"I am doing this in a certain way, but I am hoping to get a efficient and fail proof way to do this."` -- Why not show us your way and tell us what problems you may be having with it? Also, it sounds like you want to use a `Map<String, Integer>` and not an ArrayList of MyClass.

Comment: Added the way I am doing it. Please check. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: BTW, is the rawList sorted by myString?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use a map:

```
    Map<String,MyClass> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (MyClass obj: rawList) {
        MyClass other = map.get(obj.getMyString());
        if (other != null) {
            other.setMyCount(other.getMyCount() + obj.getMyCount());
        } else {
            map.put(obj.getMyString(), obj);
        }
    }
    List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```